# 'JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None' - but string does have a value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm converting an old Python 2 app to Python 3 which uses the amoffat [`sh`](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/)  module.

It loads JSON via `sh` commands, which has stopped working.

I understand from the [docs](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/command_class.html?highlight=json#runningcommand-class) that methods like `json.loads` won't work with an instance of the `sh` `RunningCommand` class even though it's string like.

However, I can't appear to get a string value that does work!

This is the original code that did work.

```py
aws = sh.aws 
......
data = aws.s3api("list-objects", bucket=s3url.bucket, prefix=s3url.path, max_keys=1)
data.wait()
items = json.loads(data)
```

But that now throws `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not RunningCommand`

So I have attempted to use both `bytes` and `str` but nothing appears to work...

Convert to string:

```py
....
data.wait()
jsonStr = str(data)
print (type(jsonStr))
print (jsonStr)
items = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

Outputs

```py
<class 'str'>
{
    "IsTruncated": true,
    "Marker": "",
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "a/path/to/object/",
            "LastModified": "2021-10-06T10:45:45+00:00",
            "ETag": "\"g41d8gd98f10b204g9800998gcf8527e\"",
            "Size": 100,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
        }
    ],
    "Name": "bucket-name",
    "Prefix": "a/path/to/object/",
    "MaxKeys": 1,
    "EncodingType": "url"
}

Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Use stdout bytes:

```py
....
jsonBytes = data.stdout
print (type(jsonBytes))
print (jsonBytes)
items = json.loads(jsonBytes)
```

Outputs

```py
<class 'bytes'>
b'\x1b[?1h\x1b=\r{\x1b[m\n    "IsTruncated": true,\x1b[m\n    "Marker": "",\x1b[m\n    "Contents": [\x1b[m\n        {\x1b[m\n            "Key": "a/path/to/object//",\x1b[m\n            "LastModified": "2021-10-06T10:45:45+00:00",\x1b[m\n            "ETag": "\\"g41d8gd98f10b204g9800998gcf8527e\\"",\x1b[m\n            "Size": 100,\x1b[m\n            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",\x1b[m\n      }\x1b[m\n    ],\x1b[m\n    "Name": "idetailaid-demo",\x1b[m\n    "Prefix": "a/path/to/object//",\x1b[m\n    "MaxKeys": 1,\x1b[m\n    "EncodingType": "url"\x1b[m\n}\x1b[m\n\r\x1b[K\x1b[?1l\x1b>'

Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but `json.loads()` claims the string version of the JSON data in your question is invalid producing a `JSONDecodeError`. The error is on the `"ETag"` line on the first backslash-escaped double quote character. It *looks* valid to me and checked out when I run it through an online JSON validator tool — so I am baffled. too.

Comment: Yeah - I noticed that as well, but thats a different error to the one I'm getting! So I was going to try to solve that later!!  At the moment it thinks the string value is `None`, rather than malformed. very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sorted it](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/issues/593) thanks to [amoffat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345059/amoffat).

Looking at the bytes output of the AWS command, it has a load of ASCII Esc characters in there for formatting to the terminal.

Turns out `sh` has a flag to stop the underlying command from thinking it's running in a terminal, and thus returns raw output (if it supports it).

```py
_tty_out=FALSE
```

You simply pass this as an arg to `sh`

```py
data = aws.s3api("list-objects", bucket=s3url.bucket, prefix=s3url.path, _tty_out=FALSE)
```

Or you can bake it in to the alias...

```py
aws = sh.aws.bake(_tty_out=False)
cmd = aws.s3api("list-objects", bucket=s3url.bucket, prefix=s3url.path)
items = json.loads(cmd.stdout)
.....
```

I assume that the newer AWS CLI added this formatting in, whereas the older version did not.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer because I don't know how to fix the problem — I'm posting it primarily to explain why the JSON in the string values being produced by the `sh` module **are** in-fact invalid. The problem is that the backslashes themselves must be backslashed-escaped because *they* need to literally be in the string that's passed to `json.loads()` for decoding.

The fix was to backslash-excape them in the value of the `"ETag"` key in the `"Contents"` list as shown:

```
import json

json_str = """\
{
    "IsTruncated": true,
    "Marker": "",
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "a/path/to/object/",
            "LastModified": "2021-10-06T10:45:45+00:00",
            "ETag": "\\"g41d8gd98f10b204g9800998gcf8527e\\"",
            "Size": 100,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
        }
    ],
    "Name": "bucket-name",
    "Prefix": "a/path/to/object/",
    "MaxKeys": 1,
    "EncodingType": "url"
}
"""

items = json.loads(json_str)
print(items["Contents"][0]["ETag"])  # -> "g41d8gd98f10b204g9800998gcf8527e"
```

Comment: So would using `json.loads(json_str.replace('\', '\\'))` work?

Comment: It probably would, but there may be some edge cases because it's so brute-force. I also don't understand why Python 2 was accepting the strings (because JSON hasn't changed with respect to this).

Comment: Makes sense. The problem after replacing the backslashes is that the `ETag` still has two double quotes in it.

Comment: @Noah: A string containing embedded double quotes in it is still a valid JSON string — escaping was invented to allow them to be represented.

Comment: But `"ETag": ""g41d8gd98f10b204g9800998gcf8527e""` doesn't parse to valid JSON

Comment: @Noah: Because that's not how it would need to be represented. To literally embed a double quote it would have to escaped with a backslash, but the backslash has to be escaped itself, hence `"\\"g41d8gd98f10b204g9800998gcf8527e\\""`.